# How to style two groups of <li> in a single line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to have two groups of list items in one line, so that one group starts from left to right and another from right to left; like so:

```
[li1 li2 li3]........................................[li6 li5 li4]
```

I have tried this:

```css
li{
  display:inline;
 }
#left{
  float:left;
 }
#right{
  float:right;
  direction:rtl;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <span id="left">
    <li> item1</li>
    <li> item2</li>
    <li> item3</li>
    </span>
  <span id="right">
    <li> item4</li>
    <li> item5</li>
    <li> item6</li>
    </span>
</ul>
```

The output works, but the code is not valid, since it uses a `<span>` directly under a `<ul>`.

What's the valid code for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there any particular reason to structure it as one complex `ul` instead of two simpler `ul`s packed in `div`? That would open some more possibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct about `<span>` directly under a `<ul>` being invalid. Here's a few solutions:

#### Give `float` to the `<li>` element directly.

```css
li{
  display:inline;
  float: left;
 }
.right{
  float:right;
  direction:rtl;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> item1</li>
    <li> item2</li>
    <li> item3</li>
    <li class="right"> item4</li>
    <li class="right"> item5</li>
    <li class="right"> item6</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Use `nth-of-type` or `nth-child`.

I think this is a nice and clean solution. Though you'd have to change the css if you add/remove items in the list:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
li:nth-of-type(n+4) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>
```

Also, it looks like you can omit the `direction: rtl` from your code.

Comment: @EricMüller OP wanted this behavior it seems. Check the question.

Comment: You're right, I assumed he wanted 1,2,3,4,5,6. It seemed more plausible to me

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this;

```
<ul>
    <li class="left"> item1</li>
    <li class="left"> item2</li>
    <li class="left"> item3</li>
    <li class="right"> item4</li>
    <li class="right"> item5</li>
    <li class="right"> item6</li>
</ul>



ul li {
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.left {
  float:left;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  direct:rtl;
}
```

You are just giving all items with a left class the float left rule, and all items with the right class a float right rule (and then changing the direction like you were originally). This way you don't have to add any extra markup or wrap the li's in a li or anything.

Answer (score 3):

You may find `display:inline-block` helpful in your coding practise. You can then use `position`ing to position these:

```css
ul{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
}
ul:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
ul:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  right: 0;
  direction:rtl;
}

ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ul > li > ul > li` structure

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right li {
  float: right; 
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="left">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="right">
    <ul>
    <li> item4</li>
    <li> item5</li>
    <li> item6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `Flexbox` and change `order` of elements

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:nth-child(3) {flex: 1;}
li:nth-child(4) {order: 6;}
li:nth-child(5) {order: 5;}
li:nth-child(6) {order: 4;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
  <li>item6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I believe OP wanted direction to be right-to-left. So the output should be `item 6 -> item 5 -> item 4`.

Comment: Running your snippet gives me `item 4 -> item 5 -> item 6`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li class="left"> item1</li>
    <li class="left"> item2</li>
    <li class="left"> item3</li>
    <li class="right"> item4</li>
    <li class="right"> item5</li>
    <li class="right"> item6</li>
</ul>



ul li {
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.left {
  float:left;
}
.right {
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="leftgrp">
    <li class="left"> item1</li>
    <li class="left"> item2</li>
    <li class="left"> item3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="rightgrp">
    <li class="right"> item4</li>
    <li class="right"> item5</li>
    <li class="right"> item6</li>

</ul>

.leftgrp {
  float:left;
}
.rightgrp {
  float:right;
  direct:rtl;
}
```

in case of responsive you can use bootstrap